# Can not build ionic version 1 from Ionic Cli 4.1.2

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an old Ionic version 1 project, and a Windows 7 machine which was formatted.

After installing Ionic Cli 4.1.2, I tried to build this Ionic version 1, project but it gives me the error message:

> Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js

Full error message:

```
ionic-v1 build
[15:26:57] Cannot load gulp: Error: Error in module: .\gulpfile.js:
Error: Cannot find module ‘internal/util/types’
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at evalmachine.:31:26
at Object. (C:\Users\myuser\myapp\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions…js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
[15:26:57] Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js
```

How can I compile the ionic version 1 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstall vinyl-fs

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/vinyl-fs
$ npm install vinyl-fs
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(cleanCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```