# Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sass, gulp

After upgrading to Gulp 4, Ionic v1 is unable to reflect my changes in build.

Upgraded gulp and gulp-sass to 4 in dev dependencies and the only error I am getting is:

```
ionic-v1 build
[14:22:07] Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js.
```

Comment: We would need to see your gulpfile as well.

Comment: for gulp to run, you need a `gulpfile.js` that has the task definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Thre is some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412341/can-not-build-ionic-version-1-from-ionic-cli-4-1-2?rq=1)

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

if it not resolve update your `gulp`

```
  npm install -g gulp
```